# CMake: fail import external library

Tags: reference, cmake, undefined, .a

I've this error that I receive when I try to compile:

```
Linking CXX executable /home/atv/catkin_ws/devel/lib/atvAcrosser/main**
CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/sendToCAN.cpp.o: In function `sendCAN()':
sendToCAN.cpp:(.text+0x432): undefined reference to `sendCanMessage(CanMsg*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/atv/catkin_ws/devel/lib/atvAcrosser/main] Error 1
make[1]: *** [atvAcrosser/CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

`Main` call the thread `sendCAN` [inside `sendToCAN.cpp`] who calls the function `sendCanMessage` in the external library `libARV6005.a`.

This is the `CMakeList.txt`:

```
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/atvAcrosser/lib/)
add_executable(main src/main.cpp src/setupPacketProtocol.cpp src/sendToCAN.cpp) 
target_link_libraries(main ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ARV6005)
```

This is the tree:

```
src
    ├── atvAcrosser
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── include
    │   │   └── atvAcrosser
    │   │       ├── ARV6005Lib.h
    │   │       ├── localPlannerCommunication.h
    │   │       ├── receiveFromCAN.h
    │   │       └── setupPacketProtocol.h
    │   ├── lib
    │   │   └── libARV6005.a
    │   ├── package.xml
    │   ├── src
    │   │   ├── localPlannerCommunication.cpp
    │   │   ├── main.cpp
    │   │   ├── sendToCAN.cpp
    │   │   ├── setupPacketProtocol.cpp
```

sendToCAN.h

```
// included dependencies
#include "ARV6005Lib.h"
//=================================
// function
void sendCAN();
```

sendToCAN.cpp

```
#include "../include/atvAcrosser/sendToCAN.h"
...
void sendCAN()
{
struct CanMsg msg;
struct CanMsg msg;
int i, result;
memset((void *)&msg, 0, sizeof msg);
msg.id = 0x33;
msg.id_type = STD_ID;
msg.length = 8;
for(i=0; i<8; i++) {
msg.data[i] = i;
}
result = sendCanMessage(&msg);
}
```

but with this `Makefile` in a tutorial example it works

```
all: main.c 
    gcc -w -o TestUtility -D_REENTRANT -I../Library -pthread ./main.c ./libARV6005.a
```

Comment: Try to make your question more understandable. If it's to complicated to understand you're less likely that we will answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that `sendCanMessage(CanMsg*)` is declared in `ARV6005Lib.h`
2. Check that `libARV6005.a` contains symbol `sendCanMessage`
3. If symbol `sendCanMessage` is not in `libARV6005.a`, find where it is and link your executable with it.
4. Run `make VERBOSE=1`, extract link command and post it here
5. In your `CMakeLists.txt` you are missing `_REENTRANT` and `pthread`. Use [target_compile_definitions](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3atarget_compile_definitions) and target_link_libraries to add it.

Answer (score 0):

The ARV6005Lib.a was written in C.
The sendToCAN.cpp has been written in Cpp.
So was sufficient 
edit the file that include ARV6005Lib.h:

```
extern "C" {
#include "../include/atvAcrosser/ARV6005Lib.h"
}
```